# Using colspan in a table with Elm

Tags: html-table, elm

I have the following (simplified) code and I would expect to have each cells of the header spanning across two cells of the second line (body) but they are not (there are aligned).

```
> import Html exposing (..) 
> import Html.Attributes exposing (..) 
> import Array exposing (..)
> 
> main =
>     Html.program
>         { init = init
>         , view = view
>         , update = update
>         , subscriptions = subscriptions
>         }
> 
> type alias Model =
>     { test : Int
>     }
> 
> 
> init : ( Model, Cmd Msg ) 
> init =
>         ( Model 1
>         , Cmd.none
>         )
> 
> type Msg
>     = Test
> 
> update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg ) 
> update msg model =
>             ( model, Cmd.none )
> 
> subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg 
> subscriptions model =
>     Sub.none
> 
> view : Model -> Html Msg 
> view model =
>     div [] [table]
>          cellHead : String-> Html Msg cellHead s =
>     td [style [("colspan", "2"), ("border", "2px solid blue")]] [s |> text]
> 
> cellBody : String-> Html Msg 
> cellBody s =
>     td [style [("border", "2px solid red")]] [s |> text]
> 
> table : Html Msg 
> table =
>     Html.table
>         [ style [ ( "border", "1px solid black" ) ] ]
>         [ caption
>             []
>             []
>         , thead
>             []
>              ([tr [] (Array.initialize 4 (toString >> cellHead) |>     toList)])
>         , tbody
>             []
>              ([tr [] (Array.initialize 8 (toString >> cellBody) |> toList)])
>         ]
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're setting `colspan` as a CSS style property, but `colspan` is an HTML attribute, not a CSS property.

```
cellHead : String-> Html Msg 
cellHead s =
    td [style [("colspan", "2"), ("border", "2px solid blue")]] [s |> text]
```

should be

```
cellHead : String-> Html Msg 
cellHead s =
    td [ colspan 2, style [("border", "2px solid blue")]] [s |> text]
```

Here, `colspan` is a function that comes from the module `Html.Attributes`

Here's what your full code would like if that was fixed (and formated):

https://ellie-app.com/c2cjHDjLva1/0

Comment: OK, I understand. Thank you.